# Showing specific Tick values

Tags: css, d3.js

Is it possible that we can specify the tick values on x axis based on the corresponding y values ? For example I have a date/time series x axis that represents dates and price values as my y axis. I want to show only the x axis values for certain values of y axis which varies based on the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the y values that the user can specify appear in the data itself and you can therefore get the corresponding x values directly, it's easy. All you need to do is filter, from your original data, everything that doesn't have a y value requested and extract the x coordinate:

```
var data = [[1,1], [2,2], [3,4], [4,1]];

var yToShow = [1, 2],
    xTicks = data.filter(function(d) { return yToShow.indexOf(d[1]) > -1; })
                 .map(function(d) { return d[0]; });
```

Then you can use the [`.tickValues()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues) to set those ticks explicitly:

```
xAxis.tickValues(xTicks);
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/joumvvtu/).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the code. Say for example I have a an array " array = [ {"first": "abc", "second": def"},{"first": "hij", "second": klm"}, ... and so on] " . How would i be able to rewrite the ytoshow so that only the x axis values of say only "klm" is shown (assuming that the array changes each time the user enters a new value. I am sorry for asking more. I'm a beginner to D3 js and apparently have a lot to learn.

Comment: Same principle: `yToShow = ["klm"]; xTicks = data.filter(function(d) { return yToShow.indexOf(d.second) > -1; }).map(function(d) { return d.first; })`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way about this is to draw no x-axis labels at all or hide them. Then use the enter() and data() functions to add labels manually. You need to decide where to put the labels beforehand and pass only the results to data(). Here a wacky wobbly untested code example snippet thingy:

```
d3.select("#myGraph .xAxis").selectAll("g")
    .data([1, 3, 13, 1355, 4678, 9999])
    .enter().append("g")
        .attr("y", - this.graphHeight)   # put them all at the bottom
        .attr("x", function(d) {return d;})
        .append("text").text(function(d) {return d;})
```

"d" in the example above is the currently iterated item from the array passed to data(). You can also pass JS objects and access their attributes. This way you could pass your own labels or the like.

Alternatively create a graph as you would normally. Then clone one of the labels from the x-axis and remove all the labels. Parse the data manually outside any enter() scopes and create clones of the label using it as template. You can still manipulate the individual x-positions and the text contents. This way is easier if you're not used to the D3 API (and I know it'S very easy to get confused by it).